# Sonata Admin for abstract class: How to filter by subclass property

Tags: symfony, sonata-admin

I have a Sonata Admin Class for my abstract entity. And in the list view I list both child entities (client, employee). I can filter them by the abstract class properties (ie: email). that works well.

But how could I add a choice (or any) filter with a property of one of the child entity? in this example i would like to filter by client->city.

seems to me like a common problem, but I couldn't find any solution yet.

```php
// parent class
abstract class Person {
 $email;
  ...
}

// child class
class Client extends Person {
 $city;
  ...
}

// child class
class Employee extends Person {
  ...
}


class PersonAdmin extends AbstractAdmin
{

  protected function configureDatagridFilters(DatagridMapper $datagridMapper)
  {
        $datagridMapper
            ->add('email')
            ->add('city'); // throw an error as it doesn't exist in the class Person
  }

...
}
```

Comment: Did you found any solution?

Comment: @abdiel yes I found, but I am not sure if it's the best and cleanest solution. I did it via orm_callback

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if it is the best solution, but it works for me

```
$city = myFunctionToGetAllCities();

$datagridMapper
    ...
    ->add('city', 
        'doctrine_orm_callback', 
        [ 
            'callback' => function($queryBuilder, $alias, $field, $value) {
                if (!$value['value']) {
                    return;
                }

                $queryBuilder
                    ->Join('App\Entity\Client', 'C', 'WITH', $alias . '.id = C.id')
                    ->andWhere('C.city = :cityId')
                    ->setParameter(': cityId', $value['value']);
                return true;
            }
        ],
        ChoiceType::class,
        ['choices' => $cities]
    )
    ...
```